# Retrofit 2.1 Internal Server Error with Post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, retrofit

I am using Retrofit 2.1 and when i am posting an object to my server, it gives me Internal server error with status code = 500, but i try to to post from my backend, it works like a charm, I am sure this is not server's problem.

Undoubtedly, i should use retrofit as a singleton:

```
    //return api if not null
HereApi getApi(){
    if (api == null) {
        api = getRetrofit().create(HereApi.class);
    }
    return api;
}

//returns restadapter if not null
Retrofit getRetrofit(){

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("my endpoint")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

and this method that i post Here object:

```
  void createHere(Here here){

    List<Here> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(here);
    Call<List<Here>> call = getApi().createHere(list);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Here>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Here>> call, Response<List<Here>> response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Here>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

I tried to post a list with single object inside and to post one object alone, but still status code is 500 ;*(

This is my api service interface:

```
public interface HereApi{

@GET("/lessons/")
Call<List<Lesson>> getLesson(@QueryMap Map<String,String> map);

@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Vary: Accept"
})
@POST("/heres/")
Call<List<Here>> createHere(@Body List<Here> list);

@GET("/heres/")
Call<List<Here>> getHeres(@QueryMap Map<String,String> map);
```

}

I have written backend in Django + Django-rest-framework:

[image: all Here objects as a list]

When I try to post from this, it just works:

[image: Posting from rest-framework UI]

I need your help guys, i have only one day to complete this project!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think there is a datetime conversation issue. 
Use Jackson formating attonation in order to properly serialize datetime field.

Comment: Thanks you! you saved my life! ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)